# slideDown div with text inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8HgVm/)

I am trying to slideDown a Div.

```
$('#rnotif').slideDown('slow');
```

The Div is sliding properly but the text content inside that looks fixed at one place.

How do i make this text to slide with the Div.

I have my div positioned `absolute` and i don't want to change that for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt... :)
The styling has not been changed, only the top position was changed from 0 to -95 px..
so with `animate({top:'0px'},"slow")`

I "slide" the element to the original postion.. meaning at 0px.. This moves everything in the `div` is moved as one element. "like a box rather then separate items." therefore creating a slide down effect without affecting anything else :)

http://jsfiddle.net/cXdGL/3/

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var html = "<div id='rnotif' style='background: #ffffcc;height: 70px;font-size: 25px;position: absolute;top: -95px;width: 100%;text-align: center;line-height: 70px;'>sliding down</div>";
    $('body').append(html);
    $("#rnotif").animate({top:'0px'},"slow")
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the text into a another tag (`b` in this example, or another `div`) and set it to `position:absolute;` and `bottom:0px;` this re aligns it as the sliding is occurring. Hope this helps.

```
    $('document').ready(function(){
    var html = "<div id='rnotif' style='background: #ffffcc;height: 70px;font-size: 25px;position: absolute;top: 0px;width: 100%;line-height: 70px;'><b style='position:absolute;bottom:0px;text-align: center; width:100%'>sliding down</b></div>";
    $('body').append(html);
    $('#rnotif').hide();
    $('#rnotif').slideDown('slow');
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8HgVm/2/

Comment: @cezarisLT  its working, but that text is not in center of div now...?  

http://jsfiddle.net/8HgVm/3/

Comment: @JoeDF nice... and the text is at it's proper position... :)

Comment: should i post it as an answer?, i didnt post it because he got it before me :P

Comment: You can post that..No problem

Comment: making that b tag absolute positioned will make it to come out of my wrapper div and as you styled it's width to 100% it is now taking up more space then i want...  any solution ?